# Css selector works on jQuery but not on css file

Tags: css-selectors

This code works on console with jquery selector, but is not working on css file. Any ideas?

.open > > > .information-icon-div

Comment: If ``.information-icon-div`` is immediate child of ``.open`` then this should work .``open >  .information-icon-div``

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.